# Two Different Answers for the Same Simple Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet with a very simple formula: =C4/D4
Sometimes, this very simple formula gives the wrong value.
[image: Same Formula, Two Answers]

- Cell C4 contains the value 390062 formatted as a number with thousands separator
- Cell D4 contains a formula which evaluates to the value 444434 formatted as a number with thousands separator.
- - This is a =VLOOKUP() formula and the displayed value is correct.
- Cell G4 contain the formula =C4/D4 which is displayed as 28%
- - This is INCORRECT! The correct value is 88%
- If I add the same formula in Cell J4 I get the correct value.
- Result for =VALUE(G4) is 0.28
- Result for =VALUE(J4) is 0.88

Furthermore;

- If I change the formatting on cell G4, it updates to the correct value.

EDIT: I might have figured this out; cell C4 is part of a Pivot Table. Is that why it's not calculating correctly?
If so, does anyone have a solve for this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). One thing to check is that **File > Settings > Calculation > Iterative calculation** is off.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: Thanks doubleunary! I tried both with Iterative Calculation enabled and disabled - both end with same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of a pivot table may change from time to time depending on things like sort order and labels, causing cell locations to vary.

To get a particular pivot table aggregate value regardless of which cell it happens to be, use the [getpivotdata()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6167538) function.

To get a particular non-aggregate value, query the *data table* rather than the pivot table, using [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343), [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) or [vlookup()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318).

Comment: Thanks doubleunary! 
GetPivotData seems to be what I need!